# Where is ${PRODUCT_NAME} defined in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I'm building a Xamarin Forms app that uses the camera. When it first loads the app asks:

```
$(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use
```

I know there are answers already for XCode but I'm using Visual Studio for Mac and Xamarin Forms. I can edit the info.plist entry to replace `$(PRODUCT_NAME)` with the name of my app but I would prefer to set `PRODUCT_NAME` to be the name of the app so that any future requirements are handled gracefully/idiomatically.

So my question, where in Visual Studio for Mac and Xamarin Forms do I set `PRODUCT_NAME`?

Comment: It's not defined in XF.  It's defined in each platform specific project that you're supporting.

Comment: Yes I get that but where in the iOS project is `PRODUCT_NAME` defined?